# React setState not overwriting object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When trying to use setState to update a customer age, the object is mutated before setState, but setState doesn't update the existing object.

```
customerOnChange(event, field) {
    //Customer age right now is 80
    var customer = { ...this.state.customer };
    customer.age = "14";
    console.log('The age of the customer is ', customer.age) //This shows up correctly

    this.setState({
      customer
    }, 
    () => { 
      console.log(this.state.customer.age) //Customer age still 80
    });
}
```

Ignore the object type being a String(I had to generalize the code before posting), property types match up correctly, but setState doesn't seem to be updating the `customer` object.

I've also tried something like

`this.setState({customer: newCustomer})`

with no luck.

Comment: it might not matter, but I would change `var customer = { ...this.state.customer };` to `var { customer } = this.state;`

Comment: I would try using `const customer = Object.assign({}, this.state.customer)` as it would remove the reference to the original object completely, removing any false negatives from React checking if the object should update.

Comment: `var customer` is a clone of `this.state.customer` since you destructured `this.state.customer`. Mutations to `var customer` will not affect `this.state.customer`. To confirm, log `customer === this.state.customer` (you'll see `false` since these are two different objects).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, as you sure you aren't getting an error thrown due to something else: https://codesandbox.io/s/10jzmjn75j

Comment: It might be that some other update happens which overwrites it. Try the function version of `setState` to guard against it and see if that works. `this.setState(({ customer }) => ({ customer: { ...customer, age: 14 } }))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you haven't bound `this` to your `customerOnChange(event, field)` event. Try writing it as
`customerOnChange = (event, field) => {`. See the snippet below.

As an alternative, you can bind `this` in the constructor, if you have one. Like so:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    customer: { age: 80 }
  }
  this.customerOnChange = this.customerOnChange.bind(this);
}
```

```js
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  state = {
    customer: {
      age: "80"
    }
  }
  customerOnChange = (event, field) => {
    //Customer age right now is 80
    const customer = { ...this.state.customer};
    customer.age = event.target.value;
    console.log('The age of the customer is ', customer.age) //This shows up correctly

    this.setState({
        customer
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.customer.age) //Customer age still 80
      });
  }
  render() {
    const {age} = this.state.customer;
    return ( 
      <div >
        <input type="number" value={age} onChange={this.customerOnChange} />
        <p>Customers Age:{age}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Thingy title = "I'm the thingy" / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```